# How to obtain AWS IOT endpoint URL from within a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot

I want some of my Lambda resources to push to an AWS IOT endpoint using `aws-sdk`'s `AWS.IotData({ endpoint: url })` function - where endpoint is a required parameter.

Right now, I am passing the endpoint URL via an environment variable to my Lambda. However, when put into a SAM/CF template, I can't find a way to retrieve my IOT endpoint URL, so that I could simply `!Ref` it.

Browsing through the [AWS resource type reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) I did not find any resource that corresponds to an IOT endpoint.

It seems like IOT endpoint can only be provisioned manually, via AWS Console (enabled / disabled), as on the screenshot below:

[image: IOT Endpoint AWS Console]

Any advice on how to have control over provisioning an IOT endpoint or at least reading the IOT URL from within a SAM/CF template, without scripting this with `aws-cli`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot provision an IoT endpoint, as the only API call that is related to an IoT endpoint is [`DescribeEndpoint`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_DescribeEndpoint.html).

What you can do is create a Lambda-backed CloudFormation Custom Resource. The Lambda function will execute the `DescribeEndpoint` call (using the AWS SDK of your choice depending on the Lambda's runtime) and return the endpoint's URL so your other CloudFormation resources can consume it.

Here's a good example on Lambda-backed Custom Resources: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone interested in the solution with CloudFormation Custom Resource, I wrote a simple Lambda and a CF template that provides an IOT endpoint address to other CF stacks.

## template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  IotEndpointProvider:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: IotEndpointProvider
      Handler: iotEndpointProvider.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: .
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Policies:
        - Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - iot:DescribeEndpoint
            Resource:
              - '*'
  IotEndpoint:
    Type: 'Custom::IotEndpoint'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt IotEndpointProvider.Arn
Outputs:
  IotEndpointAddress:
    Value: !GetAtt IotEndpoint.IotEndpointAddress
    Export:
      Name: IotEndpointAddress
```

## iotEndpointProvider.js

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n" + JSON.stringify(event));

    // For Delete requests, immediately send a SUCCESS response.
    if (event.RequestType == "Delete") {
        sendResponse(event, context, "SUCCESS");
        return;
    }

    const iot = new aws.Iot();
    iot.describeEndpoint({}, (err, data) => {
    let responseData, responseStatus;
        if (err) {
            responseStatus = "FAILED";
            responseData = { Error: "describeEndpoint call failed" };
            console.log(responseData.Error + ":\n", err);
        } else  {
            responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
            responseData = { IotEndpointAddress: data.endpointAddress };
            console.log('response data: ' + JSON.stringify(responseData));
        }

        sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);
    });
};

// Send response to the pre-signed S3 URL 
function sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData) {

    var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
        Status: responseStatus,
        Reason: "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.logStreamName,
        PhysicalResourceId: context.logStreamName,
        StackId: event.StackId,
        RequestId: event.RequestId,
        LogicalResourceId: event.LogicalResourceId,
        Data: responseData
    });

    console.log("RESPONSE BODY:\n", responseBody);

    var https = require("https");
    var url = require("url");

    var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
    var options = {
        hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
        port: 443,
        path: parsedUrl.path,
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "",
            "content-length": responseBody.length
        }
    };

    console.log("SENDING RESPONSE...\n");

    var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
        console.log("STATUS: " + response.statusCode);
        console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
        context.done();
    });

    request.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("sendResponse Error:" + error);
        // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
        context.done();
    });

    // write data to request body
    request.write(responseBody);
    request.end();
}
```

Comment: Does it mean every time I need to get endPoint url I have to call this lambda function?

Comment: That depends on your needs but in this case lambda will be fired once as a custom resource, during CloudFormation template deployment to provide the URL to all resources  which need to know that URL.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you tell me how exactly I can refer to that url within same repo plus other repos? can I do something like this -   environment:
    IOT_END_POINT: ${self: Outputs.IotEndPointAddress} ?

Comment: I'm just really new to CloudFormation and still figuring out lot of things